# How are Spring MVC Controllers being bound to JSP pages?

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller, controller

Hi I am new to spring and I am trying to develop a simple portlet that accepts users first and last name and saves it to db using hibernate.

Basically I cannot figure out how the jsps and controllers communicate; I am missing some chunk here.

This is my first controller that needs to be called (where do I mention so?)

```
    package codes.controller;

    import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;

    import codes.base.User;
    import codes.service.UserService;

    @Controller(value="SimpleUserController")
    @RequestMapping(value = "VIEW")
    public class SimpleUserController {

    // -- auto-wiring of service dependency
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userService")
    private UserService userService;

    // --maps the incoming portlet request to this method
    @RenderMapping
    public String showUsers(RenderResponse response) {
        return "home";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({ Exception.class })
    public String handleException() {
        return "errorPage";
    }

    // -- @ModelAttribute here works as the referenceData method
    @ModelAttribute(value="user")
    public User getCommandObject() {
        return new User();
    }
}
```

Initially I am displaying a home.jsp that will display the form with two input boxes and a submit button.

```
<%@include file="include.jsp" %> 

<portlet:actionURL var="addUserActionUrl">
    <portlet:param name="myaction" value="addUser" />
</portlet:actionURL>

<form:form name="home" commandName="user" method="post"
    action="${addUserActionUrl}">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name:<font style="color: #C11B17;">*</font></td>
            <td><form:input path="firstname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name:<font style="color: #C11B17;">*</font></td>
            <td><form:input path="lastname" /></td>
        </tr>

        <table align="right">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </table>

</form:form>
```

This JSP should call the action method in the AddUserController.java:

```
package codes.controller;

import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;

import codes.base.User;
import codes.service.UserService;  

@Controller(value = "AddUserController")
@RequestMapping(value = "VIEW")
public class AddUserController {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("userService")
  private UserService userService;

  @RenderMapping(params = "myaction=addUser")
  public String showRegisterPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    model.addAttribute("users", getUsers());
    return "addUser";
  }

  public List<User> getUsers() {
    return userService.getAllUsers();
  }

  @ActionMapping(params = "myaction=addUser")
  public void addBook(@ModelAttribute(value = "user") User user,
        BindingResult bindingResult, ActionResponse response,
        SessionStatus sessionStatus) {
    if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        userService.addUser(user);
        response.setRenderParameter("myaction", "users");
        sessionStatus.setComplete();
    } else {
        response.setRenderParameter("myaction", "addUser");
    }
  }
}
```

This time this firstname+last name should be saved in the db AND the screen should refresh to show a new form that will have a dropdown with the current users' names in the database and another first name and last name form fields. If you select a username from the dropdown the form fields are populated and you can edit these values and click on UPdate button to save the values in DB. Otherwise you can add a new user to the database using submit button.

addUser.jsp:

```
<%@include file="include.jsp" %> 

<portlet:actionURL var="addUserActionUrl">
<portlet:param name="myaction" value="addUser" />
</portlet:actionURL>
<portlet:renderURL var="homeUrl">
<portlet:param name="myaction" value="Users" />
</portlet:renderURL>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/userRelated.js"></script>

<form:form name="addUser" commandName="user" method="post"
action="${addUserActionUrl}">
<form:select path="model">
<form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" id="userList" onchange="showHide()"/>
<form:options items="${users}" />
</form:select>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name:<font style="color: #C11B17;">*</font></td>
        <td><form:input path="firstname" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name:<font style="color: #C11B17;">*</font></td>
        <td><form:input path="lastname" /></td>

    </tr>

    <table align="right">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" />SUBMIT</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="update"  value="SUBMIT" />UPDATE</td>
    </tr>
    </table>        
</table>

</form:form>
```

I am hiding and unhiding the SUBMIT/UPDATE button using onchange of dropdown. How do I call different functions in the addUsercontroller depending on the button available?

Comment: There is a cool guy, who has a lot of answers for your questions. Try to 
look through his blog http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-mvc-tutorials/

Comment: To totally become an expert in this read about a realization of MVC in Spring, and a conception of FrontController

Answer (score 0):

by updating the action attribute of form element with javascript

Comment: should I say something like this:<form:form name="home" commandName="user" method="post"
    action="/addUserController/AddUser"> ?

Comment: the action should be whatever requestmapping you want to "call"

Comment: can one form be mapped to 2 different functions on submit as in addUser.jsp?